# Devise Security Extension Undefined Method

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

```
NoMethodError in Devise::SessionsController#create

undefined method `unique_session_id=' for #User:0x007f82b86fa4b8
```

After installing Devise_Security_Extension, setting session_limitable in the user model, and creating the migration for the_resources table I get the above error.

Initially my app loads fine, however as soon as credentials are input and a new session created the error appears.

I'm not sure how to troubleshoot it, it's a bit beyond my scope.

I'm running Rails 3.2.6, Devise 2.1.2, and Devise Security Extension 0.6.2.

Anyone experience a similar problem or have advice?

Answer (score 1):

```
Undefined method `unique_session_id=' for #User:0x007f82b86fa4b8

1) It means, it is looking for unique_session_id field in users table, which is missing
2) In docuementation, they meant "the resources table" means, model / table which we are using for authentication, which is "users table" in your case.
```

So, you need to remove the migration for "the_resources table" and add "unique_session_id" field to users table. that will fix your error.

Hope It Helps :)